# How to organize express middlewares better?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I'm using node with express and the following code is working as expected.

file **app.js**

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    fs.mkdir('uploads/', function (e) {
        if (!!e && e.code !== 'EEXIST') {
            console.log('Error while trying to create upload folder: ' + err);
        }
        next();
    });
}, upload.single('file'));
```

My question is whether there is better way to write it?
I mean to separate the function logic to other file and require it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I whould suggest to create file '{project_root}/middlewares/fsUtils.js':

```
function createFolderIfNotExists(folder) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        fs.mkdir(folder, function (e) {
            if (!!e && e.code !== 'EEXIST') {
                console.log('Error while trying to create upload folder: ' + err);
            }
            next();
        });
    };
}

module.exports = {
    createFolderIfNotExists: createFolderIfNotExists
};
```

Then you can use it like:

```
var fsUtils = require('./middlewares/fsUtils');

app.use(fsUtils.createFolderIfNotExists('/uploads'), upload.single('file'));
```

Not an ideal approach though. It is better to move initialization logic to separate script and run it at application startup, so that at the moment when you are expecting 'uploads' folder to exist in the filesystem - it will be there already.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of extends [Danila Shutov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35278931/691711).  I would also suggest that you learn to use [`express.Router()`](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router).  These can help you organize your routes a little better by making sub-routes refactorable to single files.

---

## Just using `require`

Consider the single file below, where you define all your routes but import individual handlers with a `require`.  It cleans it up a bit, but you're still going to have a mountain of routes defined in a single file.  It will also be a hassle if you ever change the path of those routes.

**index.js**

```
app.use("/", require("./root-route"));
app.use("/users", require("./users-route"));
app.use("/users/create", require("./users-create-route"));
app.use("/users/delete", require("./users-delete-route"));
app.use("/comments", require("./comments-route"));
app.use("/comments/create", require("./comments-create-route"));
app.use("/comments/delete", require("./comments-delete-route"));
```

---

## Using `express.Router()`

Now consider this multi-file solution that uses `express.Router()`.  None of the routers actually have to know about one another or even be in the same file.  Additionally, you can bind the router to whatever path you want and then switch it without having to do a find/replace on your whole project.

For example, if we didn't actually want `users` to be the path to whatever logic `./users-route` does, we could mount it at `players` and it would automatically work.

**users.js**

```
var usersRoute = require("express").Router();

usersRoute.use("/", require("./users-route"));
usersRoute.use("/create", require("./users-create-route"));
usersRoute.use("/delete", require("./users-delete-route"));

module.exports = usersRoute;
```

**comments.js**

```
var commentsRoute = require("express").Router();

commentsRoute.use("/", require("./comments-route"));
commentsRoute.use("/create", require("./comments-create-route"));
commentsRoute.use("/delete", require("./comments-delete-route"));

module.exports = commentsRoute;
```

**index.js**

```
app.use("/", require("./root-route"));
app.use("/users", require("./users"));
app.use("/comments", require("./comments"));
```

Comment: In the large-scale apps one should use routers carefully:
http://techblog.netflix.com/2014/11/nodejs-in-flames.html

Not sure if performance issues were fixed in later versions of Express. Please let me know if they are.

Comment: @DanilaShutov That's super interesting.  I didn't know about that.  So does that mean defining all your routes without a `Router()` would be preferred or does the problem stem from them refreshing the routes?

Comment: I agree with you that their problems were caused by tricks with refreshing route handlers (it's even kind of memore leak). But still this article shows that routers can be point of pain, if you have a lot of them bound to endpoints.